# RT8188EUS USB WiFi adapter

Tags: wifi

How?!
Do I need a driver or something?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8021q                  32768  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
stp                    16384  1 garp
llc                    16384  2 garp,stp
r8188eu               401408  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
sha256_generic         16384  0
libsha256              20480  1 sha256_generic
cfg80211              770048  1 r8188eu
rfkill                 32768  2 cfg80211
raspberrypi_hwmon      16384  0
snd_bcm2835            24576  0
bcm2835_codec          36864  0
bcm2835_v4l2           40960  0
bcm2835_isp            28672  0
snd_pcm               106496  1 snd_bcm2835
v4l2_mem2mem           36864  1 bcm2835_codec
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     28672  3 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
videobuf2_dma_contig    20480  2 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec
videobuf2_memops       16384  2 videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  4 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
videobuf2_common       61440  5 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
snd                    77824  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
vc_sm_cma              32768  2 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_mmal_vchiq
videodev              241664  6 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
mc                     45056  6 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,videodev,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
fixed                  16384  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  475136  18
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules $ find ./ -name *8188*
./5.10.17+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu
./5.10.17+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
./5.10.17-v7l+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu
./5.10.17-v7l+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
./5.10.17-v7+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu
./5.10.17-v7+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
./5.10.17-v8+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu
./5.10.17-v8+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe -c | grep 8188
alias usb:v056Ep4008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v07B8p8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v07B8p8188d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* rtl8192cu
alias usb:v07B8p8188d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8712u
alias usb:v0B05p18F0d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v0BDAp0179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v0BDAp8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v0BDApFFEFd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v0DF6p0076d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2001p330Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2001p3310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2001p3311d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2001p331Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2357p010Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2357p0111d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
alias usb:v2C4Ep0102d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* r8188eu
```

With a default installation of Pi OS lite the interface `wlan0` shows up in `ip a` on the first boot, so I configured it as follows.

**/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0**

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="mini3"
    psk="TOP_SECRET"
}
```

**Connected but not working**

The AP `mini3` is Debian running on an old Mac Mini so I can see in its `/var/log/syslog` the attempts of the Pi to connect.

What seems to happen is that the Pi tries over and over again to connecto the Mini and sometimes it eventually does for a while -- and `ip a` on the Pi shows the correct IP address that I have set for  it's MAC address in `dnsmasq.conf` on the Mini.

On the Mini this seems to correspond to the disconnections

```
...
Oct  5 14:21:01 mini31 hostapd: wlx00e032800384: STA 00:e0:2d:2b:29:d3 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
...
```

And this is what's going on on the Pi:
The only thing that stood out in the `syslog` was:

```
...
Oct  5 14:01:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[378]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.131
Oct  5 14:01:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[378]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.1.131/24
Oct  5 14:01:35 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
Oct  5 14:01:36 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
Oct  5 14:01:37 raspberrypi kernel: [  103.078393] R8188EU: sta recv deauth reason code(2) sta:02:e0:32:80:03:80
Oct  5 14:01:37 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=02:e0:32:80:03:80 reason=0
Oct  5 14:01:37 raspberrypi kernel: [  103.095419] R8188EU: indicate disassoc
Oct  5 14:01:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[378]: wlan0: carrier lost
...
Oct  5 14:01:39 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 02:e0:32:80:03:80 (SSID='mini31' freq=2452 MHz)
Oct  5 14:01:39 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: Failed to add supported operating classes IE
Oct  5 14:01:39 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
Oct  5 14:01:39 raspberrypi kernel: [  104.721242] R8188EU: assoc success
Oct  5 14:01:39 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[312]: wlan0: Associated with 02:e0:32:80:03:80
...
```

which -- in particular the `Failed to add supported operating classes IE` -- got me thinking that it could be a driver issue -- the RT8188 seems like a bit of a lemon?

For the short time it *appears* to be connected the network is not really usable. For example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [32.6 kB]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [393 kB]
Ign:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
Err:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 46.235.231.151 80]
Fetched 26.0 kB in 3min 33s (122 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 46.235.231.151 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

**fars-robotics driver**

I tried these (using `15.10.63-v8-1457` (from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188eu-drivers/) for my `uname` of `15.10.17+`) but after rebooting the Pi `wifi0` has disappeared from `ip a` and I have to start over with a new flash of Pi OS on my SD card.

Comment: Your wpa_supplicant.conf file is missing `country=GB`. Get rid of that /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0 file, it's not needed with RaspiOS as dhcpcd5 will start supplicant.

Comment: If I delete `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` then the system doesn't even try to bring the interface up, and `ifup` doesn't work.

Adding `country=GB` made no difference.

The `raspi-config` program says: `Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant`.

Starting over with a new image...

Comment: Unsurprisingly, doing the same produces the same result: network connection intermittent and unusable.

Comment: `country=GB` seems to have stopped the looping connect/disconnect, but `apt-get update` still errors.

Comment: Used a USB ethernet adapter instead in order to be able to move on to other stuff (RaSCSI) but I messed that up too and had to start over again. Just thought I'd have another look at this and maybe try https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu (since the Fars robotics just made `wlan0` disappear), but now with the configuration as above (plus `country=UK` and a reboot) it's working! (so far...?!)